# Single Gradient in Multiple Container In Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using React With Tailwind 
I need to Apply same Gradient to Navbar as well as Sidebar 
but applying gradient on both give different flow.
Please give me solution!

```
 <navbar className="flex h-16 w-full bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-800 to-blue-800 justify-center"></navbar>

 <sidebar className='flex absolute h-full w-1/4 bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-800 to-blue-800'></sidebar>
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: maybe having the gradient in the sidebar the same length as the navbar ( 100vw or 100%), and then clipping that gradient to the size of the sideBar so you only show the part of the gradient you need to see. May be you will need to have it positionned as absolute wich is not very handy, but not sure, it might be worth trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make sure your navbar is 100vw, then you can add Pseudo-element to the sidebar and add gradient background to it. If there is a vertical scrollbar, it may shift the gradient a bit. You can apply the same trick to the navbar to avoid this behavior, but `overflow:hidden` may affect some overflow element like menu dropdown. In this case, you may nest another full width, height,  `absolute` div then add Pseudo-element into it in your navbar.

```
<div className="flex h-16 w-full justify-center bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-800 to-blue-800 overflow-y-scroll"></div>

<div className="relative flex h-full w-1/4 overflow-hidden from-gray-800 to-blue-800 before:h-full before:absolute before:w-screen before:bg-gradient-to-r before:content-[''] before:-z-10"></div>
```

Code can be found [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/X7paeBWu0B)